# Bounding a Certain Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, derivatives

I'm self-studying the $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ edition of Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference* and I'm having trouble following a derivation they give (on pp. 72-73).

Suppose we want to find a function $g(x,t)$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{tx}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}\right]_{t=t'} \leq g(x,t)
\end{equation*}

for all $|t'-t|\leq \delta_{0}$ (where $\delta_{0}>0$) and such that

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x} < \infty.
\end{equation*}

It is easy to determine that

\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{tx}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}\right| = \left|x\right|e^{tx}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}.
\end{equation*}

They go on to define $g$ as

\begin{equation*}
g(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\left|x\right|e^{(t-\delta_{0})x}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}\,&\mbox{ for }x<0\mbox{ and}\\
\left|x\right|e^{(t+\delta_{0})x}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}\,&\mbox{ for }x\geq 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Defining the function $g$ as they do, the integral over the negative real numbers involves $e^{-\delta_{0}x}$ in which $-\delta_{0}x>0$, and the integral over the non-negative real numbers involves $e^{\delta_{0}x}$ in which $\delta_{0}x\geq 0$, but either way it seems like $e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2}$ will ensure the integral is finite.

It's not clear to me why it is necessary to define the function differently depending on the sign of $x$. Is this done to ensure the inequality? Or is it done to ensure that $g(x,\cdot)$ has finite integral over $\mathbb{R}$?

*Edit*: I don't think it has to do with integrability. For $x\geq 0$, they show that one can write

\begin{equation*}
g(x,t) = xe^{-\left[x-(\mu+t+\delta_{0})\right]^{2}/2}e^{-\left[\mu^{2}-(\mu+t+\delta_{0})^{2}\right]/2}
\end{equation*}

so that integrating this function over $[0,\infty)$ amounts to calculating the (surely finite) mean of a normal distribution over half of its support. They do the same for $x<0$:

\begin{equation*}
g(x,t) = |x|e^{-\left[x-(\mu+t-\delta_{0})\right]^{2}/2}e^{-\left[\mu^{2}-(\mu+t-\delta_{0})^{2}\right]/2}.
\end{equation*}

But the reasoning seems to hold equally well using $t-\delta_{0}$ or $t+\delta_{0}$ in either case, the difference amounting to a shift in the mean of the normal distribution.